# Power Automate - Split String by ONE delimeter and ignore any other delimiters that may be found

Tags: split, delimiter, power-automate

I have created a flow in Power Automate that when a new email is received it converts the body of the email from HTML to text and then a formula to split the text using the ":" delimiter and using the "last" expression. For example:-

```
last(split(outputs('Split_Body_Text')[0],': '))
```

The problem I am facing at the moment is if when someone completes the form which is summarised in the body of the email I am splitting, using say the "|" delimiter,a space or a "," or anything other than the colon specified in the formula, the flow doesnt work correctly. I need to basically ignore any other delimiters so it still splits the text correctly.

Any help regarding this solution would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Here is a screenshot of the flow.....

[image]

Gosh I thought the explanation was pretty straight forward......

I have a order form that is filled out and every order is sent to me by email. I want to split the forms answers and put in an excel document which is working great except when there are delimiters that the customer has put in the form. For example:-

**SPECIAL INSTRUCTIONS:** THIS UNITS IS #1 BUT LOTS #2.

**SPECIAL INSTRUCTIONS:** is the form field and ****THIS UNITS IS #1 BUT LOTS** #2.** is the customners response.

When the flow ran, it split the string as follows:-

**SPECIAL INSTRUCTIONS: THIS UNITS IS #1 BUT LOTS**

What the flow should have done there is split ALL of the text after the ":" but it brought in the form field (SPECIAL INSTRUCTIONS:) which is shouldnt have and missed the text "#2.".

So basically i want it to ignore any other delimiters (whether or not there is another term to use, I apologise for being incorrect) and treat it as part of the text split.

The other problem is that if the field is left blank, it splits the form field name, which I don't want. If the field is left blank, I want the cell in excel to be blank as well. Hope that makes sense.

I am not sure what else you need from me?

the formula shown in my original post is the same throughout the flow.

If there is anything else I can provide let me know!

Thank you.

I have attached a screenshot of the following:-

1. Excel Document Table Columns
2. A copy of the email body content that is split
3. The raw output of my current flow - I have shown some dummy data which i highlighted in red, which is the data i need split and added to excel. The issue is that some people use #, or carriage returns, so it stuffs up the flow as I explained previously. The other issue is that if the field is left blank, it shows the field name in excel rather than a blank cell. The numbers in the square brackets (i.e. [0], [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBTsj.png) etc) refers to the line number of each field from the raw output.
   So I am still unsure what to do!

   [Raw Output Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBTsj.png)
   [Excel Table Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDjWQ.png)
   [Email Body Content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TExI8.png)

Comment: I am getting a bit confused about the *ignore any other delimiters* comment. If a split character is not found it will simply not split the text at all. So, in the current setup it will ignore any other kind of delimiters. Or do you mean that the expression needs to be smart and needs to check which delimiter it needs to use based on the content available?

Comment: You need to provide some sample data so we can recreate the flow ourselves along with the definition of each step.

Comment: I have added some information in my post, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of how a split normally should operate. As you can see it should return the whole item.

*Unless your original data is already split into multiple items. Which would mean you have to look at your Split_Body_Text action configuration/outputs. In your original expression you are referring to the first item of that action output by using the [0] index.*

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for that - i have added some other information for you as I am still confused with what I need to do to fix it!